# Sell "create a post", paid account for post creation

Tags: plugins, posts, e-commerce

How can in wordpress, one sell the "create post" option

To elaborate more. One has to pay an amount before he can make create a post on the wordpress site.

MORE ELABORATION

Suppose a person pays $20, he gets to write a post on wordpress. This is just like a paid listing website. If the person wants to create another post, he has to pay another 20 Bucks.

Comment: Well, if someone is giving a negative point, should they state a reason for doing so.

Comment: Do you mean a premium/paid account for post creation? Rephrase your question if you dislike negative votes and don't want them.

Comment: @Rutwick : with all good intentions, it never occurred to me my question was a bit ambiguous. Yet what I want to achieve has been made more clear by description of the question.

Comment: Okay. Enable registrations on your site, when a user buys a premium account (or a single pay, whatever), set an option or user meta that tells he has paid the amount. Then check if that value is set against him, if yes, assign him edit_post capability when he logs in (or create a new post creation area to restrict it according to your criteria).

Comment: But how do I restrict him by enabling him to create only one post per payment

Comment: After payment, save in usermeta `can_post` as `true` and change it to `false` when the user publish a post and check if `can_post` is `true` everytime a user tries to post

Comment: Exactly! That's how you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments you can make use of [user meta functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference#User_and_Author_Functions) to store user-specific information and use [capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) (or some more simple check) to control if user can create a post.